# Are directory_iterator and/or recursive_directory_iterator guaranteed to return relative paths?

Tags: c++, c++17

Are `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` and/or `std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator` **guaranteed** to return `std::filesystem::directory_entry` objects with paths relative to the base directory they were initialized with?
Or **may** they return entries with absolute paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Filesystem draft N4100](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4100.pdf):

> The result of calling the path() member of the directory_entry object
>   obtained by dereferencing a directory_iterator is a reference to a
>   path object composed of the directory ar gument from which the
>   iterator was constructed with filename of the directory entry appended
>   as if by operator/=

So it seems that the answer is: the path is relative to the one that the iterator has been constructed with.

Comment: Finally fully tested it and for my setup the behaviour you described is true.  
My expectations that the entry path would be purely relative were completely wrong and sadly I don't know which example code led me to believe that.  
Further clarification, when the iterator is initialized with an absolute path the resulting entries have absolute paths too.